# HTML input box, how to prevent key repeat when key is held down

Tags: javascript, html, input, keyboard-events

Is there a way to prevent auto-repeat behavior in an HTML input (`type="text"`)?

So that when you hold down the a key while in the input box, only one character is used, instead of repeating the character until the user releases the key.

I know how to do this for key-events in the browser but HTML input `type="text"` boxes seems to be in a world of their own.

Comment: do some research about the `keyDown`, `keyUp` and `keyPress` listeners, with `preventDefault` and/or `stopPropagation`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have actually done a ton of research on 'keydown, keyup, keypress' listeners but I have NOT thought to researched on how to use these listeners with 'preventDefault and/or stopPropagation. This is good information. I hope it helps me with my end goal which is to prevent auto-repeat type behavior in input boxes specifically. I can prevent auto-repeat with keys held down in the browser but not in html text input boxes. :-(